# How to display only revision numbers from svn log command?

Tags: svn, logging

I am new to svn. I want to know how to display revision changes checked in between two dates.

I have used this command

```
svn log -r {2013-11-10}:{2014-01-01} url
```

It shows me correct output. But I want to display only revision numbers not log messages.
I want output like this

```
r2077
r2078
r2079
...
```

Comment: Is `grep`? a good solution for you?

Comment: svn log -r {2013-11-10}:
{2014-01-01} url | grep ... after that??

Comment: see below for complete line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
svn log -r {2013-11-10}:{2014-01-01} url | grep -e "r[0-9]. |" | grep -oE "r[0-9]."
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to match. Using cut seemed to work better than extended grep.

```
svn log -r {2013-11-10}:{2014-01-01} url| grep "r[0-9\s]*\|" |cut -d\| -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
svn log -r {2013-11-10}:{2014-01-01} url | sed -n '/^r[0-9]/p' | cut -d '|' -f1
```